# Pause loop in Excel VBA until another Sub is finished

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to write a macro to achieve the following:

- Open IE, and log into a finance site
- Open a CSV file of historical prices for a symbol and move it to another workbook
- Repeat step 2 for several symbols

I have achieved the first two steps, but I can't find a way to loop it so that it then downloads the rest of the symbols. It seems that all my attempts at looping either:

- Run the loops too quickly
- For some reason stop my code from working as before.

My code works fine as long as I don't have the For ... Next i loop, but as soon as I add that it navigates to the site but when prompted to open the CSV file it doesn't get opened.

Below is a simplified example of my code. I navigate to Google to simulate the login step (which should only happen once). Then I navigate to the actual address of the CSV, and then call on the MoveIt Sub to place it where I want it.

As it is it works fine, but the moment I add the For...Loop (Currently marked as comment in the code), it stops opening the file.

I also tried a Do.While loop in the first Sub (also marked as comment) so that it wouldn't do anything until the second Sub is done, but it also doesn't work.

```
Public i As Integer, j As Integer

Sub GetHistoricalCSV()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim web As String

i = 1


Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer 'create a new instance of ie
ieApp.Visible = True

ieApp.Navigate "https://google.com" 'go to login page
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'For i = 1 To 3 'This is the start of the loop

j = 0

web = "http://www.global-view.com/forex-trading-tools/forex-history/exchange_csv_report.html?CLOSE_" & i & "=ON&start_date=09/16/2018&stop_date=09/16/2018&Submit=Get Daily Stats"

ieApp.Navigate web

    'Wait to make sure IE has navigated and is prompting to open or save the CSV
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    SendKeys "(%o)" 'Open the CSV


    'I need to wait for the file to open, so I schedule the rest of the code on a new sub
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "MoveIt"

'Do Until i = j 'This is telling the code to wait until then next sub has finished
'    DoEvents
'Loop

'Next i 'This is the end of the loop

End Sub
```

The next Sub moves the opened sheet to a workbook named "Text.xlsx"

```
Public Sub MoveIt()
Dim Ct As Integer
Ct = 0
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "exchange*" Then
        Ct = Ct + 1
        wb.Activate
        Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

If Ct = 0 Then MsgBox "File not open"

ActiveSheet.Move After:=Workbooks("Test.xlsx").sheets(Workbooks("Test.xlsx").sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Exchange" & i

j = i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome!  Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and **how to create a [mcve]**... It will be easier to help you if you include only the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I tidied the spacing/indentation of your code - I think you have a few issues and incomplete code (for example `If Ct = 0 Then End` ... end "what"?).  I'd suggest you add the line `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help identify undeclared/mishandled variables & objects, and once the code compiles properly, [edit] your question with the updated code -- a [mcve].

Comment: @ashleedawg, “End” is a valid though not recommendable statement

Comment: you are using sendkeys which is pretty flakey though sometimes helpful with IE. Looking at other looping windows to find the pop-up window or whether the CSV actually has a download url and us that to download instead. Store that path in a variable and use that to open. Why are you making IE not visible then visible again - cheek by jowl?

Comment: Along the theme of the searching for a window, if you know part of what the CSV title/window caption will be is to have a boolean loop function, with upper timeout limit that introduces a wait until a window with that string is found or the whole thing times out.

Comment: you don't select any element for the csv so can you do a straight file download with URL using binary download/urlmon?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I have reformulated the code so that only the necessary parts are included and linking to publicly accessible CSVs so that you can replicate the execution.

Comment: @QHarr, I can't do a straight file download because I need to be logged in - it would be so much easier otherwise. Making IE not visible and visible again was to ensure it was the active window for SendKeys to work. I tried a number of loops until a certain amount of time passed, but none of them worked - just like the DoUntil that I've put in the updated code.

Comment: But if you have done the login in earlier code is the sessionid not set to then use file download or does it not work that way? Never tried  tbh.

Comment: @QHarr, you were actually right! Once I'd logged in once I can simply open the web address directly - that's solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped. I will type up in case happens for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not selecting an element to initiate the download you should be able to try a binary file download/urlmon download using your constructed url direct. Provided you have already logged in earlier in the code a sessionid/cookie will hopefully be in place and still valid. Use a function to download that returns the download full path and collect those to later open downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Get & Transform to solve your problem?

It looks like you may need to set up some parameters based on the dates, but that can be done fairly easily. I struggled to figure out a solution to this for awhile, found some help on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/8f4oln/help_with_get_transform_parameters_and_api_urls/) and ended up with the following query in this [Workbook](https://github.com/prp1277/resources/blob/master/Excel/PQ/ParameterTables.xlsx) on GitHub to pull information from the iex API.

```
// If you need more context see the workbook posted above
let
  Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
  URL = Parameter{0}[Value],
  Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL)),
  #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
  #"Converted to Table"
```

Let me know if you're able to use this or if you need any more help!